# Density of the set of convex polygons in the Banach-Mazur distance

Tags: banach-spaces, sg.symplectic-geometry, convex-geometry, convex-polytopes, polygons

Is the set of convex polygons dense in the set of convex domains in $\mathbb{R}^2$, for the Banach-Mazur distance?

Any insight for a negative or positive answer is very much welcome!

Comment: The BM distance is usually defined as a distance between normed spaces. What is the distance between convex subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ ?

Comment: Well, you just translate as follows: for every convex domain in R^2 there is a normed space having this domain as the unit ball. So you define the BM distance of two convex sets as the BM distance of the two normed spaces having these domains as their unit balls

Comment: But you can also be more rigorous as: K,L convex bodies, then $d_{BM}(K,L)=inf\{c\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}|K\subset L\subset cK\}$.

Comment: Ok, then I guess in the first definition you consider absolutely convex domains. In the other definition, don't you have a factor $1/c$ in front of the first $K,$ that would make $d_{BM}$ simmetric?

Comment: Yeah i think, you refer to the original definition, however, is equivalent to this last one I gave you (which I personally like more). See for example Corollary 2.5 in
https://www.universiteitleiden.nl/binaries/content/assets/science/mi/scripties/bachrozendaal.pdf

Comment: The paper you give requires $L=T(K)$ for some invertible linear map $T$, and that $T$ need not be identity, so the definition you give is wrong. (Another way to see its failure is to consider the case that $K$ and $L$ do not contain each other)

Comment: And also, I think you should replace "convex domain" by "closed (or open) convex neighbourhood of the origin".

Answer (score 1):

Let $U\subset \mathbb R^2$ be a bounded open convex neighborhood of $0$. For every $\epsilon>0$ we have $\displaystyle \overline U=\bigcap_{H\supset U\atop H \text{ closed half-plane}} H \subset (1+\epsilon)U$, therefore $\displaystyle   \bigcap_{H\supset U\atop H \text{ closed half-plane}} H \setminus (1+\epsilon)U=\emptyset.$ Hence, by compactness,  the intersection is already empty on a finite sub-family of these half-planes $H_1,\dots, H_m$, so $\displaystyle U\subset \bigcap_{1\le j\le m} H_j \subset (1+\epsilon)U$, which exhibits a convex domain bounded by a polygon close to $U$.

***[edit]*** I think that given $\epsilon_0>0$ one can produce another positive $\epsilon<\epsilon_0$ and polygon whose boundary is inscribed to $(1+\epsilon)\partial U$ and circumscribed to $\partial U$, by the  construction sketched here below:

Fix a point $x_0\in\partial U$.  Form a sequence (depending on $\epsilon$,  $y_k=y_k(\epsilon)$,  for $k\ge0$,  of points on $(1+\epsilon)\partial U $, starting from $y_0:=(1+\epsilon)x_0$, and defining inductively $y_{k+1}\in (1+\epsilon)\partial U$ as the point on the  line from $y_k$ which is tangent to $\partial U$ and such that $(y_{k+1}-y_k)\cdot y_k>0$ (this is to fix a sense of rotation). The key point is that for each $k$ the point $y_k$ depends continuously from $\epsilon$.
Call $m_\epsilon$   the first index $m$ such that the corresponding polygonal paths with vertices $y_0(\epsilon),\dots y_m(\epsilon)$ cross itself. Since $m_\epsilon\to\infty$ as $\epsilon\to0$, by continuity there is $\epsilon <\epsilon_0$ such that $y_{m_{\epsilon_0}}(\epsilon)= y_0(\epsilon)$, which means that the polygon with vertices $y_k(\epsilon)$ is circumscribed to $\partial U$ and inscribed to $(1+\epsilon)\partial U$.

Comment: I think your answer is right. However I have a questions before accepting it. Can we show that this polygon is inscribed in the boundary of $(1+\varepsilon)U$ and circumscribed in the boundary of $U$ at the same time?

Comment: Actually not by the above argument; it just  produces a convex polygon between $U$ and $(1+\epsilon)U$, whose boundary could  even be disjoint from both $\partial U$ and  $(1+\epsilon)U$. This argument can be repeated in any dimension though.

Comment: However  I think one can  produce a polygon as you say  with a possibly smaller $\epsilon$: I’ve added a sketch of the construction.

Comment: This is good @pietromajer. However I don't see clearly why the $\varepsilon<\varepsilon_0$ is, as a matter of fact, a positive number. I mean, why the closing of the produced polygon happens strictly before $\varepsilon=0$? Can you hopefully elaborate a little bit more in this detail. Thanks very much for taking the time with this btw.

Comment: The reason is that this would happen exactly in case $U$ itself is a polygon.  If it is not a polygon, more and more edges are needed for a complete turn by a polygonal between $\partial U$ and $(1+\epsilon)\partial U$, as $\epsilon\to0$.

Comment: Yes I agree, but I don't see why would the polygonal path close up strictly before $(1+\varepsilon)\partial U$ collapses into $\partial U$, at least for the smooth boundary case.

Comment: Then if you appreciated the answer to the original question, you may want to ask a separate post with a further well stated question, in order to get a complete answer :)